How do I trigger an Action when any letter key is pressed?
I'm working on a crossword app, where I want each square to respond to any letter key by changing the contents of that square.
If I use SingleActivator, it seems to accept only one logical keyboard key as a trigger, but even if it could take a LogicalKeyboardKeySet or list of keys, I would need to put in all the logical keys.
If I use a CharacterActivator, it again only accepts a single character.
What I'd like to do is something like a regex match for [a-zA-Z] and then activate on any key that matches. Is that possible?
